# Dijkstra algorithm modification with increasing link cost

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I was thinking of implementing a simple load-balancing scheme by modifying Dijkstra in that way:

1. Calculate shortest path
2. Increase cost of those links which belong to that shortest path by a number CostInc.

The idea is to make the same route less attractive for next call of Dijsktra's algorithm.
But I have questions:

1. Does it really work, because I can't find an info about such modification
   2.What is an optimal CostInc number. It should be related with present link cost or number of nodes N, or with both of them?
   Appreciate any advices.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Look into A* algorithm (which is a generalisation), taking care of not overestimating the heuristic.

Comment: That sounds sort of like several of the proposed approximation algorithms for the multicommodity flow problem.

Comment: The task is to lead mobile nodes (people) to the exit of a building in case of emergency.